# Choosing the right answer for an answerable, but not practically testable, question

Tags: discussion

If a question is asked which cannot be tested out for some reason (say hardware limitations, for example something related to supercomputers), but has a definitive answer (let's assume the question has a Yes or No answer).

If two answers are posted, one saying 'Yes' and the other saying 'No', how should the OP select the right answer when they don't know the answer themselves? Must they rely on others' comments?

EDIT: I changed the title and part of the body to indicate "not practically testable" instead of 'theoretical' because that's what I meant (as indicated in my example), but may 'theoretical' was not the most appropriate word to be used.

Comment: Theoretical questions don't belong here. You need a practical, concrete problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @fbueckert I changed the question to indicate a more appropriate meaning. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If the asker is asking about something which they can't test, then it's not very practical, is it?

Comment: It takes at least two users to complete a good Q+A, one that posts the best answer and one that can verify that the answer is correct.  Q+A can't work with one of them unable to get the job done.  Pivotal to SO's reason for being and former success, forums did not work like that.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the OP asking the question? "Practically testable" vs. "theoretical" is just semantics in this case, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, this question is the type of question you're asking about. This is a theoretical question with no clear-cut answer. There's no "right" definitive answer to this question. "It all depends"...

I'd wager that most, if not all, theoretical questions have a much more detailed answer than just *"yes"* and / or *"no"*. On the other hand, they tend to be too broad, and as such, a poor fit for SO.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant "not practically testable" and not "theoretical"

Comment: @rahs I think the English saying here is 'potato potahto'. Doesn't really matter how you call it. Stack is mean for practical problems. Not practically testable, or theoretical, in this situation, is the exact same thing, from a 'Stack isn't a place for these' perspective